# Updating multiple records/rows selected by two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been trying to write an update query that would update several rows/records so that i could test update trigger with batch updates. I've seen somewhere it done something like that

```
update atbv_Sales_OrdersLines 
    set Amount = case OrderID
                when 5 then 10
                when 6 then 11
    end
where OrderID in (5, 6)
```

but I need to select rows based on two columns and I can't manage to do it
tries something like

```
set Amount = case OrderID, ProductID
            when 6, 1 then 10
```

but as expected it's no good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about...

```
update atbv_Sales_OrdersLines 
   set Amount = OrderId + 5
 where (OrderId = 6 and ProductID = 1) or
       (OrderId = 5...)
```

or

```
update atbv_Sales_OrdersLines 
   set Amount =
         CASE
           WHEN OrderId = 6 and ProductId = 1 THEN 11
           WHEN OrderId = 5 and ProductId = 2 THEN 10
           ...
         END
 where ...
```

You should probably read [Microsoft's documentation on the CASE expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) and pay especial attention to example "H. Using CASE in an UPDATE statement"

Comment: error `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.`

Comment: @NulisDefo - misplaced parenthesis.  thanks for the catch.  Corrected it.

Comment: @Agapwlesu Tried second one (as it is more clear to me) and it works. I assume `where` clause here is not necesary, right?

Comment: Yes it is, if you only want to set the Amount of those records where OrderId is 5 or 6.  Even if you manage to set Amount to the value it was before, for all other records, that would be hugely wasteful/inefficient.

Comment: it would be setting Amount to record where OrderID is for example 5 and ProductID is 1

Comment: I am not clear what you mean, but basically, you want to use the WHERE clause to limit the records that you update to only the records you need to update.  Even if the CASE expression does something to limit which `Amount` values get changed, you do not want that CASE expression to be run on any records that you do not mean to UPDATE, and you limit that with the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
case
when OrderID in (6, 1) then 10
...
end
```

Comment: but if i name only one column `OrderID` where will it take the other number from?

Comment: If you use the form "case OrderID when <value> then ..." then <value> can only be a single value from OrderID.  

However, if you use the form "case when <condition> then ..." you can have any conditional statement you want in that <condition>  You can say "orderID = 6 and otherThing = 'abc'" or "orderID is not null and orderID in (3,4,5,6)" or whatever logic you want that resolves down to a true/false value.

Comment: oh, so pretty much what Agapwlesu showed. Good explanation, but your answer doesn't seem to reflect it. Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, I didn't see his answer, it's better and should be accepted.